# Activity Passing Data to Fragment through callbacks

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, callback, android-fragmentactivity

I got a situation here .

I have `FragmentActivty` which holds a `Fragment` . when i click on a button in `Fragment` i am going to a `Activty` . when i reach the activity **i do something** which will affect the data displayed in `Fragment` where i came from. So in order to bring that changes in fragment i would like to give a callback from the `Activity` to `Fragment`. First i thought of implementing `onActivityResult`. But i realized it's not what i needed.

Is my approach is wrong?? Please guide me

```
MyActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

MyActivity holds

```
MyFragment extends Fragment
```

From here i'm going to

```
SecondActivity extends Activity
```

from `SecondActivity` i need to get a callback to `MyFragment` . Is there anything wrong with my approach ??

EDIT:

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private FrameLayout frameLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.framelayout);
         loadFragment();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    private void loadFragment() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.framelayout, myFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
}
```

MyFragment.java

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view, container, false);
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                callActivity();

            }
        });

        return view;
    }



    private void callActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
//      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.e("MyFragment Inside", "Onresultttt");
        if (requestCode == 10) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Log.e("Result code", Activity.RESULT_OK + " okkk");
            }
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.e("Result code", Activity.RESULT_CANCELED + "cancelll inside fragment");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "second activity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondactivity_view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // super.onBackPressed();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
        Log.e(TAG, "result setted");
        finish();

    }
}
```

Comment: use interface to handle call backs

Comment: `startActivityForResult` from fragment

Comment: @Raghunandan i told first i thought of that. but i realize i am wrong

Comment: @edwin what is wrong?

Comment: @BaZinga how can i make interface to push data back to fragment. i thought of that. but i am blank about the implementation logic . if you don't mind can you elaborate??

Comment: @Raghunandan  startActivityForResult not getting triggered . i search for this  issue got many solutions. but it's works fine in sample project. but when it come to my project . it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your situation correctly, then the correct way of handling the communication is to have SecondActivity pass back information to MyActivity, which will in turn configure it's instance of MyFragment directly. You don't want to be accessing Fragments from Activities unless the Fragment is attached to the Activity.

As for how to do the communication, as you suggested, one way of doing it would be through the use of startActivityForResult(). See this answer for more details: [How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result)

Just a note about startActivityForResult(). If you are calling it from the Fragment then your Fragment will receive the result, not your Activity. There are also some other issues with calling startActivityForResult() from a Fragment, so I would generally recommend that you instead call it from the Activity and therefore handle the result from the Activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, INTENT_CODE);
```

The best practice way of communicating from a Fragment to an Activity is by defining an Interface in the Fragment, which the Activity implements.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    public interface MyFragmentListener() {
        public void onMyFragmentEvent();
    }

    public void startTheActivityForResult() {
        ((MyFragmentListener)getActivity()).onMyFragmentEvent();
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements MyFragmentListener{
    @Override public void onMyFragmentEvent() {

    }
}
```

The Fragment then simply casts the reference to the Activity it is attached to, knowing that the Activity must implement the Listener, thus allowing you to reuse the Fragment in other Activities.

Comment: Well i tried this . But onActivityResult get triggered before going to secondActivty . when coming back to fragment nothing happens

Comment: Also the link onActivityResult is implemented in FragmentActivity . will this affect other fragments that used via FragmentActivity??

Comment: In the onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) method, are you checking that the resultCode is the same as what you set in the Intent (INTENT_CODE)? There may be other intents coming through which you'll want to handle differently. Also, check the edits I made to my post, you may be passing in a reference to the Fragment when you create the Intent, which would explain why your Activity's onActivityResult() it isn't being called.

Comment: So you are suggesting me to handle the onActivityResult in FragmentActivity . and push data from FragmentActivity to the fragment i need callback. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Correct. Handle the Intent in the FragmentActivity. From the FragmentActivity you should have a reference to your Fragment so you can just call it directly to configure it.

Comment: well i had posted my code . you can see i am passing getActivity() from Myfragment .Still i got invoke at Myfragment not in FragmentActivty? do you think if i change the   callback to Fragmnet activty. it will work as you said

Comment: I believe you are correct and I was mistaken. The call to startActivityForResult must be called from the FragmentActivity(). I will edit my answer.

Comment: well i don't think this what i needed . here you are mentioning how to get a call back from the FragmentActivity that holding MyFragment right ??

Comment: Correct, this is one of the potential hazards of using startActivityFromResult from a Fragment. Another is that nested Fragments are simply not supported and can produce unexpected results.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41379/discussion-between-theit-and-edwin)

Answer (score 1):

Refer this question it will help you understand what is happening: 
[onActivityResult is not being called in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment)